# Favorites list doesn't display closed status indicator

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, closed-questions, bookmarks

The favorites list does not seem to show the closed status indicators that the other question views do, even though it *does* highlight deleted questions. For example, [my list of favorites on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone?tab=favorites&sort=newest) currently has the following closed question as the first entry, and there's no indication that it's closed:

[image: closed question without status indicator]

For consistency, this view should display the expected closed status indicator.

Comment: +1 for free hand.... [ Closed ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice find.  This was just a matter of not having the data available at the time the favorites list gets rendered.  This should be corrected shortly.